# Why can I only enable code migrations if also enable automatic code migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

There was a breaking change so we decided to reset migrations, but now If we don't put the `-EnableAutomaticMigrations` option `Enable-Migrations` doesn't work.
My connection string is in my web project that is set as the startup project.

This are the steps we took:

**First** We deleted the Migrations folder and the database completely.
Then When we do:

```
enable-migrations
```

We get:

> Checking if the context targets an existing database...
>
> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending
>   changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending
>   model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration.
>   Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to
>   enable automatic migration.

I don't understand this error, there is no database, there are no migrations, to what pending changes does it refer to? (I dont even have pending chanves in git)

If then We do

```
enable-migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

It works, but when We follow it with:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreation
```

It creates an **Empty InitialCreation migration** and it creates the database with the tables that correspond to my model. But doing this We can't get the scripts for creating the database for the first time. I don't get what is going on.
It seems the first time it uses some Automatic migration.

Why can't We `enable-migrations` without  `-EnableAutomaticMigrations`?

**Update**

After talking with Steve Green, I think it could be useful to add part of my DbContext and Initializer

```
public class ApplicationDatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDatabaseContext()
            : base("MyConnectionStringName")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDatabaseContext>(new ApplicationDataInitializer());

            if (!Database.Exists())
            {
                Database.Initialize(true);
            }
        }
```

And my DatabaseInitializer:

```
public class ApplicationDataInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDatabaseContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDatabaseContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);

            CreateData(context);
        }

        private void CreateData(ApplicationDatabaseContext context)
        {
            //Add data here
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the initializer MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion set.

Second, You should not need to enable automatic migrations. To reset migrations you don't have to delete the entire folder (especially if you've done some seeding or other customizations in the Configuration() class). Just delete the individual migrations then add a new baseline migration:

`add-migration MyStartPoint -IgnoreChanges`

This will take a snapshot with no code in the Up() since you don't really need that to generate a script to create the database. So now `update-database -Script -SourceMigration $InitialDatabase` should create a script you can use to create a new database.

Another option is to use an [initializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) like CreateDatabaseIfNotExist which will do exactly that.

Comment: We have the CreateDatabaseIfNotExist initializer.  I am new to EF and migrations, looking at some Microsoft Tutorial they deleted the entire folder, that is why we did it. Also that is how many places advice to reset migrations. How do you set the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion when you are using a CreateDatabaseIfNotExist initliazer?

Comment: You don't need both. MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion will create the database if it does not exist as long as you have that baseline, initial migration. Put it in the static constructor of the context.

Comment: Hi Steve, I added my DbContext constructor and the Initializer to my post. We had this same things before and had no issue resetting the EF Migrations. And now all of the sudden doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Also, and this is what confuses me. When you first start with migrations, you have no database, no migrations folder, and you do enable-migrations to start, so when you delete everything, in theory you go back to that stage, but yet, is not working.

Comment: Have you tried replacing CreateDatabaseIfNotExist with MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion? That's what we use and we are able to both create new databases and update existing ones as long as we have that initial migration in there. Otherwise you can try checking `context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true);` before initializing.

Comment: Hi Steve, I tried that and it didnt work either. When using the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion, for some reason, Visual Studio would freeze. And the other option didnt make it work any different. I tried lots of things, finally, if I create the database, empty, the enable-migrations works as usual. But if there is no database it doesn't. It is rather odd, because it used to work, I dont really know what change. Thanks for your help!